# What defines a hyper carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legendes, what defines a hyper carry?
What the champions can fit the role and why it isn't used more frequently?

Comment: From where comes this term? Never heard it before.

Comment: @Gnoupi think Faceless Void in Dota2, who can just stasis a team and cap their asses 1v5. THAT is what a hyper carry is.

Comment: @user1337 - Ah, I see. The only dota-like I actually invested time into is LoL, so that would explain why I wasn't familiar with the term.

Answer (score 14):

A "Hyper Carry" by definition is someone that scales so well into Late Game, that he becomes unstoppable.

In LoL, there are no True Hyper Carries, due to the fact that all carries can be focused and shut down at some point, although if we look at Vayne, she can be defined as a "Hard Carry" (amongst others) due to the fact that she reaches a higher peak at end game (with her True Damage, which scales with ATK speed, which you can find on the common ADC items such as SotD and Phantom Dancer)

There are two exceptions, mainly due to the fact that a fed champion "Can be shut down by CC".
This does not apply to Irelia and Olaf. Once one of these has an advantage in gold and levels (aka "fed"), they are very VERY hard to stop, mainly due to their damage output, tankiness, sustain, and immunity to CC.

So, conclusion:

- LoL has "No Hyper Carries" (Faceless Void waves Hello)
- LoL has several champions with a higher potential when fed. (Olaf, Irelia for example)
- LoL also has simple carries that naturally reach a higher peak at end-game than other, known as "Hard Carries" or "Late Game Carries". (Vayne, Kog'maw and others)

**Additional details:**

Due to popular demand, I am now apparently forced to list the most dangerous champions to feed.

1. **Irelia** - Heavy CC reduction, innate tankiness and regeneration, True damage. Very hard to stop after she has an advantage.
2. **Olaf** - Short CC Immunity + tankiness buff, heavy True Damage on demand, very VERY tough once at an advantage (the less Current HP he has, the faster he attacks. The more MAX HP he has, the more damage he deals)
3. **Farm-carries: Nasus, Sion and Veigar** - Long story short, they have good CC and an INFINITE stat potential due to the fact that their stats scale with their farm (Nasus Q Bonus Damage, Sion HP (with Atma's, AD as well), Veigar Ability Power)

*Gimme moar and I'll fill the list*

Comment: Indeed, LoL is made in such way that they tend to limit group CC (and the ones with it are usually not the damaging ones), making it complicated to effectively destroy a team all alone (if the game went more or less normally).

Comment: Limit group CC? "Not damaging ones"? What about a Veigar at 70 minutes? Also, who needs group CC if you got BRAND? HAH!

Comment: Technically, Veigar's CC can be avoided, as it occurs only from crossing the perimeter. He doesn't directly stun a group, the group has to walk into his trap. Also, Veigar is more of a "one target burst". But that's just nitpicking. In general, LoL's CC are less dramatic than DOTA2's ones, that's all I was saying.

Comment: I Agree there is no Hyper Carry in lol. I don't think there's much debate on this. In competitive games (not low elo - low levels) there is NO champion no matter how fed he is that can't be stopped and I would venture to say that there is no champion who can kill a whole team 1v5. Of course it must have happened a few times but those are exceptions of exceptional players and we cannot say that those X champions are Hyper Carries.

Comment: Poppy is the only real champ that can be 'unstoppable'. Maybe she is the only true 'hyper' carry?

Comment: Poppy is unstoppable for a short while, after which she can be bursted. Same thingfor tryndamere.

Comment: @user1337 do not forget kayle please, also you might want to add nasus and sion to the hard carries, who scale into late-game, imagine a nasus with 500 extra dmg on q, trinity and survivability, even though he got terribly nerfed and is to no point viable anymore...

Comment: @Vogel612 What makes Kayle so unstoppable? Kayle is 3/4/5 sec. immortal. Olaf and Irelia are immortal 24/7, hehe.

Comment: the funny thing is that kayle will shred hp even much stronger than olaf and irelia together.

Comment: Ok, high damage output... but how does that make her a -hyper carry-?

Comment: Jax ? The more damage he gets the more tanky he is ... area stun, Stacking attack speed, gap closer/escape. Once he is fed he is hard to deal with. Like written in his lore he was'nt given a real weapon cause he is too strong :-p

Comment: @Hystic Jax only got more tank as he was getting damage BACK IN SEASON 2. He doesn't have that passive anymore. His new passive is more attack speed for every attack. Yes, one half of his Ult got moved to his innate. The other remained = every 3rd attack nukes for AP.

Comment: Source ? i got that : Grandmaster's Might
Every third consecutive attack deals additional magic damage. Additionally, Jax can activate this ability to strengthen his resolve, increasing his Armor and Magic Resist for a short duration.

Comment: The presence of an unknown fighter who was unbeatable. For this reason, XXX, created special restrictions for Jax to fight under ..... as a means of protest, he permitted himself to fight using only a brass lamppost

Comment: @Hystic Yeah, when RIOT said "unbeatable", they bloody mean it.

Comment: This answer isn't entirely correct anymore. Also, I'm pretty sure that Riot refers to some of their champions as hyper-carries, like Vayne and Kog'Maw.

Answer (score 6):

Hyper-carry is actually an old/obsolete concept that no longer applies.

Basically, regardless of how well/poorly a champion was doing, after hitting the 50-55 minute mark, certain champions become incredibly strong.

This was prevalent during season 1/early or pre-season 2. Champions like `Olaf`, `Irelia` and especially) `Master Yi` could have catastrophic impact in teamfights/duels once they finish the bulk of their build (for Irelia that meant `Trinity`+Survivability; for Yi it meant Attack Speed + Life steal; and I never played Olaf back then so I can't comment) and regardless of how hard they had been shut down throughout the game, they will tear you apart after that point.

Basically what I'm trying to say is that Irelia could jump in vs 5, kill 2 and be on the verge of killing the 3rd before being shut down. And when I say jump in vs 5, I mean SOLO vs 5; so you can imagine.

Item and champion balancing has taken care of that though.

Bit of nostalgia: at the time when i was playing Irelia, the phrase 'better nerf Irelia' was already lol-lingo so you can imagine how incredible she was.

Comment: upvoted because this is in all honesty the correct answer to the question, there were hyper carries when the game was still new, tryndamere still brings back many a good memory, but none of these champions can be categorized as such anymore simply for the fact that Riot finally started to balance the game(champions and items). Although there are still hard carries, there are no longer hyper carries within the game. Difference between a hyper and hard carry, hard carry can be focused down with 5 people attacking, a hyper carry could "Not" be killed regardless of focus.

Comment: "Was"? Even today, I still hear "Rengar is OP, better nerf Irelia"... *sigh* nostalgic indeed, hehe.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know about "hyper", but if it's similar to hard carry - carry, who can carry hardest with full inventory and max lvl, I think it would be Tristana. She can easily reach max as with less as items, her range max lvl is awesome and she has escape. You just stand behind your team and kill enemies with max as.